# google script WebApp get parameter from URL

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, web-applications

I have a google script WebApp with the link for example

https://script.google.com/a/macros/domain.com/s/******/dev?v=repDetails

On the users side - in HTML code - can I get the "v" value?
I've tried to search similar issues and developed this

```
 var getUrlParameter = function getUrlParameter(sParam) {
    var sPageURL = ScriptApp.getService().getUrl()
        sURLVariables = sPageURL.split('&'),
        sParameterName,
        i;

    for (i = 0; i < sURLVariables.length; i++) {
        sParameterName = sURLVariables[i].split('=');

        if (sParameterName[0] === sParam) {
            return sParameterName[1] === undefined ? true : decodeURIComponent(sParameterName[1]);
        }
    }
};

var id = getUrlParameter('v');
alert(id)
```

but it returns an error "ScriptApp is not defined"

Any solution here?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Server side libraries like `ScriptApp` is not available client side.

To get the url  query parameters and hash on the client side, use [`google.script.url.getLocation`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/url):

```
google.script.url.getLocation(location=>console.log(location.parameter))
```

Answer (score 1):

To run a custom App Script on the client side you have to use:

```
google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(
      (result) => {
    //do something with the result
    }).withFailureHandler(
      (error) => {
    //do something with the error
      }
    ).nameOfYourFunction(params)
```

on your case:

```
google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(
      (params) => {
    //do something with the result
    }).withFailureHandler(
      (error) => {
    //do something with the error
      }
    ).getUrlParameter(sParam)
```